# Double buffering in Java on Android with canvas and surfaceview

Tags: java, android, canvas, doublebuffered

How does one go about doing this? Could somebody give me an outline?

From what I've found online, it seems like in my run() function:

1. create a bitmap
2. create a canvas and attach it to the bitmap
3. lockCanvas()
4. call draw(canvas) and draw bitmap into back buffer (how??)
5. unlockCanvasAndPost()

Is this correct? If so, could I get a bit of an explanation; what do these steps mean and how do I implement them? I've never programmed for Android before so I'm a real noob. And if it isn't correct, how DO I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's already double buffered, that's what the unlockCanvasAndPost() call does. There is no need to create a bitmap.

Comment: I don't quite get it. So, I just draw everything I need between lock and unlock and... double buffering happens on it's own? Don't I need to also draw BEFORE I lock? Sorry, I need this explained in the most basic way possible...

Comment: @TheBeatlemaniac: When you're drawing on a `Canvas` after `lockCanvas()` has been called, you're actually drawing stuff on the *next* frame, while the *current* frame is being displayed. An `unlockCanvasAndPost()` call will switch the next frame buffer with the current frame buffer in order to display an updated `Canvas`.

Comment: The bitmap portion comes in handy if you want to be able to zoom in/out and move your "worskpace" around.

Answer (score 2):

The steps from [Android Developers Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/1QN1qX_Qey4/Vnz5H49RjtoJ) say that you need a buffer-canvas, to which all the renders are drawn onto.

```
Bitmap buffCanvasBitmap;
Canvas buffCanvas;

// Creating bitmap with attaching it to the buffer-canvas, it means that all the changes // done with the canvas are captured into the attached bitmap
tempCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
tempCanvas = new Canvas();
tempCanvas.setBitmap(tempCanvasBitmap);

// and then you lock main canvas
canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();              
// draw everything you need into the buffer
tempCanvas.drawRect.... // and etc
// then you draw the attached bitmap into the main canvas
canvas.drawBitmap(tempCanvasBitmap, 0, 0, drawView.getPaint());
// then unlocking canvas to let it be drawn with main mechanisms
getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

You are getting the main buffer, which you are drawing into without getting different double-buffer canvas' on each holder's lock.

Comment: I think the variable names are all kinds of out of whack here?