# How can I control Android's double buffering behavior?

Tags: android, animation, doublebuffered, double-buffering

I am writing a small animation where an area should start on the left hand side of the screen, and widen to cover the entire screen, and bounce back. I want the speed to vary, but I am finding that when the speed is high, there are many "ghost" images appearing.

I tried with a basic `View` at first, and then changed to a `SurfaceView`. It was still ghosty. I looked into drawing on a separate bitmap (buffer) as presented [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538423/double-buffering-in-java-on-android-with-canvas-and-surfaceview).

My current version of the drawing code looks like this:

```
Bitmap tempCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas screenCanvas = currentCanvasHolder.lockCanvas();
Canvas buffCanvas = new Canvas();
buffCanvas.setBitmap( tempCanvasBitmap );
blackRect.set( widthToPaint + 1, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight );
colorRect.set( 0, 0, widthToPaint, viewHeight );

buffCanvas.drawRect( blackRect, blackPaint );
buffCanvas.drawRect( colorRect, colorPaints[ currentColor ] );

screenCanvas.drawBitmap( tempCanvasBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());

currentCanvasHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost( screenCanvas );
```

But it is still being ghosty! To aid in explaining, I have attached a couple videos of the animation in its current state:

- [**Fast animation ghosting**](https://youtu.be/K00u__5HqPo)
- [**Slow animation ghosting**](https://youtu.be/0gQMyXnDGaw)

---

In trying to understand the problem more, I created a new project with a line which bounces back and forth. As recommended by the Android documentation regarding buffering, I am clearing the entire canvas each time. However, I still am seeing the line "repeated" several times throughout the animation (after it stops it's only appearing by itself, which is what I expect).

The project can be found at https://github.com/thedanielgray/android-flickering-demo .  Does Android combine all the previous buffers somehow while rendering the animation? I tried to draw several lines without clearing the canvas and it seemed that there were more than 2 canvases/buffered that were being exchange at the different steps of the animation. What options to I have to control this buffering behavior?

Comment: Don't create Bitmap and Canvas objects again and again if you are reusing. If blackRect is used for screen clearing then why is it not starting from 0,0?

Comment: I use `blackRect` for coloring the part that is not colored (`widthToPaint` is the dividing X coordinate where the colored part ends and the black part starts).

Comment: That is why i asked that. Paint everyting to black first then paint some part of it to any color you want.

Comment: Tried that and it still looks the same :( I guess I am missing something else...